# Return row where diff between start/end date is highest

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have something similar to:

```
1786    GIG 1   83936   0   3   2014-03-03 10:00:00.0000000 2014-03-03 12:59:59.0000000
1787    GIG 1   83936   0   3   2014-03-03 13:00:00.0000000 2014-03-04 15:59:59.0000000
```

I would like to return the row with the biggest diff between start/end date.

I tried this but it doesn't like the `max` in the `group by`

```
select  id,
        keyword,
        shortcode
from keywordschedules 
where keyword = 'gig' 
group by max (datediff(minute,datefrom,dateto)),
            id,
            keyword,
            shortcode
```

It should return the row with 1787

Comment: Are you trying to get the row with biggest difference of all the rows for each ID with the biggest difference ?

Comment: No, I have multiple rows with keywords that have start/end date, i'm trying to pick the rows with these keywords that has the max start end date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally like to use `ROW_NUMBER()` to assist with this:

```
WITH RankedResults AS 
(
    SELECT id, keyword, shortcode,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY keyword 
                              ORDER BY DATEDIFF(n, datefrom, dateto) DESC) rank
      FROM keywordschedules
)
SELECT id, keyword, shortcode 
  FROM RankedResults
 WHERE rank = 1 AND keyword = 'gig'
```

The common-table-expression (CTE) at the top assigns a ranking to each group of keyword ordered by the time difference in descending order (so the largest gap gets assigned 1). Then in the final query you ask for the keyword you want where the rank is 1.